# Insert GET variable into string in PHP

Tags: php

This works:

```
Welcome <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?><br>
```

But this doesn't:

```
'html' => 'Hello $_GET["name"];',
```

How should I code this?

Comment: Is this in a .php file ? Perhaps the file you edited is not mapped to be processed by php, usually this is done for each extension.

Answer (score -1):

it should be `echo "Hello $_GET['name']";`, [single quotes](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) show exact values, you can use [double quotes](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) if you are using variables.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "Hello {$_GET["name"]}";
```

This should do.

Correction:
Its not a good practice to use double quotes inside double quotes as pointed out in comments. So the correct thing should be `Hello {$_GET['name']}`

Comment: The syntax highlighting here on SO should show you there's a problem with your answer.... double quotes inside double quotes isn't a good idea

Comment: @MarkBaker How so..I am running this exact line in my server right now. I dont see any error.

Comment: @MarkBaker Oh yeah! Its not a good idea..but its not an error. but you are right. Better follow the guidelines

Comment: @MarkBaker Nope. Here is my code <?php
$_GET["name"] = "Rash";
echo "Hello {$_GET["name"]}";

?>

Comment: it's not an error, but it looks so very WRONG... and undoes all the other Q/A's here that say, basically,  "don't use the same quotes inside a string as you used to enclose the string"